# Is it possible to merge the partition type of EFI System into Linux Filesystem?

Tags: partitioning, fedora, merge, boot-partition

The partition of my machine which is mounted at `/boot` is almost full, thus I cannot update my kernel anymore. Meanwhile there is another partition which is mounted at `/boot/efi` and it is totally free. I was wondering if it is possible to allocate some free space of `/boot/efi` to `/boot`.

These are the details regarding the mentioned partitions:

- *Device*: `/dev/sd6`

  - *Partition Type*: `Linux FileSystem`
  - *Content*: `Ext4--Mounted at /boot`
  - *Capacity*: `98.2% full`
- *Device*: `/dev/sd7`

  - *Partition Type*: `EFI System`
  - *Content*: `FAT32--Mounted at /boot/efi`
  - *Capacity*: `0.0 % full`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need EFI for booting. A better approach is to buy a larger storage drive (HDD or SDD) and do an image transfer on the new drive.
There are tricks to also modify contents on the EFI drive using manual edits which are also not recommended except in critical situations (f.e. fixing a messed up boot loader or firmware upgrades for the mobo).

Windows also adds a recovery helper drive which should also be untouched. The EFI partition works similar between Win and Linux (with the exception of size - as you guessed Microsoft opts for the smallest version which is not always a good idea, but that is another story).
Also I don't think you can use a bootloader from a separate drive.

Resizing the EFI is also not advised.

If you REALLY must do this, then at least use GParted. You can load up a GParted image on a bootable USB. That means you must either do a "forever" boot order off of a removable drive before local drives or do the one-session change using the boot selection when the PC starts. When booting off a GParted USB, a GNOME wizard will start. My recommendation is to go with the defaults. You'll have most of the drivers that you'll need there (generic video drivers, input, output and network) as well as software (a minimalistic browser if you need some online info/reference/tuts) and of course, the partition manager (which has a GUI, so no worries about memorizing any command line instructions or making complicated shell scripts).

You can reduce the partition size which should not be below 150-200 MB (what I recommend, but the real minimal value is 100). Keep in mind this is not guaranteed to work. There are a number of caveats there (the classical old-skool FAT32 FS vs ext3/ext4) and the issue of resizing the PRIMARY partition from the start to end.

You can find it here: https://gparted.org/

Since I cannot guarantee that this will work or that it will not damage your system, as well as the other suggestion of a new drive, the first thing you should do is the first best practice rule since the beginning of time: back-up. So before you either move on a new HD or experiment with repartitioning an EFI drive, get a drive image and store it somewhere so you can recover it later.

Having said that, I stand by my original suggestion and the safest bet to not mess up your system is to image-out the contents on a new larger drive, format this one and mount it as an extension for the main partition for additional storage space.

Good luck !

P.S. I noticed you don't have a dedicated linux swap drive either... not necessarily a bad thing but it is always a better idea to have one (just don't go overkill with the size). Unlike Windows, I think 8GB should be enough. You might even get away with 4-6, but 8 is a generally accepted value.